# Mocking a method to produce different values on every call

Tags: c#, .net, stack, moq

As part of a test, I wish to mock a Get() method using Moq such that it returns a popped value from a Stack every time it’s called.

Unfortunately, Moq’s Setup() methods are only run once and thus, each Get() within my test returns the same top value from the stack on every call.

My test kicks off a process in which multiple Get() methods are called. How would I mock this Get() method such that it pops a new value every time of off a orderedGetOutputs stack?

Comment: Without looking at your code, it nearly impossible to suggest any solution. One suggestion I have is that you need to make sure that you add different items to stack so that stack.Pop can get you back the different item. You can change the behavior of the stack.Pop. It will return the top most item available in that stack. So if you want different items to be popped then you need to push different items first.

Comment: Oh my stack is already initialized with several values, I felt I didn't need to mention that. My main issue is that the mock only returns the top value of the stack. I appreciate your help though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
public interface ISomeInterface
{
    public string SomeValue { get; set; }
}

[Fact]
public void PropertyReturnsDifferentValueOnEachCall()
{
    var stack = new Stack<string>();
    stack.Push("World");
    stack.Push("Hello");

    var mock = new Mock<ISomeInterface>();
    mock.SetupGet(s => s.SomeValue).Returns(() => stack.Pop());
    // Because the method signature of stack.Pop() matches
    // the expectation of Returns(), you could also write
    // mock.SetupGet(s => s.SomeValue).Returns(stack.Pop);
    var instance = mock.Object;

    var resultOne = instance.SomeValue;
    var resultTwo = instance.SomeValue;

    Assert.NotEqual(resultOne, resultTwo);
}
```

When mocking a normal method you use `.Setup()`, but when you mock a property getter you have to use `.SetupGet()`. Regardless of what you mock, the `.Returns()` overload takes also a matching `Func<>` that can do whatever needed.

Comment: This is what I am doing, but the problem with this is that it will return the top value, "Hello". for both calls to instance.SomeValue. This is because the SetupGet() runs only once and sets SomeValue to return "Hello". If you run this test, I believe it will fail. I really appreciate your understanding of my question and your efforts in helping me.

Comment: I ran this test on my machine and it didn't fail. 

Comment: And it even runs on my internet: https://dotnetfiddle.net/AvgVKD

Comment: I think your failure is you did `.Returns(stack.Pop())` and not `.Returns(() => stack.Pop())`.

Comment: Ah, you're right! My apologies. Thanks for the dotnetfiddle link, I just tried it out. I had done stack.Pop() and that was my issue. What is this distinction between stack.Pop() and stack.Pop/() => stack.Pop() called?

Comment: Method group vs function call

Answer (score 2):

Moq has a specific function called “SetupSequence”. This will allow you to chain setup and return calls. Either that or you can pre populate the stack with information you’ll need for each call.

Comment: My stack was instantiated and prepopulated. I wanted to essentially hardcode a sequence of various results from calls to Get() in my test. Stacks turned out not to work so I implemented SetupSequence as you recommended and hard coded each successive Returns() with I would had in the stack. This works great, thank you!